# Eigen householderQr gives nan/infs on specific singular matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I tried to solve linear system using `colPivHouseholderQr`, but received nans/infs for some specific matrices.

Here is example:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd lhs {
    {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      },
           {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      },
           {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      },
           {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      },
           {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      },
           {0.293596, 0.293596, 0.293596, 0.293596, 0.293596, 0.      ,
            0.31533 , 0.293596},
           {0.32315 , 0.32315 , 0.32315 , 0.32315 , 0.32315 , 0.31533 ,
            0.      , 0.32315 },
           {0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.293596,
            0.32315 , 0.      }
};
Eigen::VectorXd rhs = Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(lhs.rows());

const Eigen::VectorXd solution = lhs.householderQr().solve(rhs);
std::cout << solution << std::endl;
```

This code prints something like:

> -nan
> -nan
> -nan
> -nan
> -nan
> -nan
> -nan
> inf

If i change solver to, for example, `colPivHouseholderQr` i get valid solution. I also tried to perform SVD on my original matrix, and to run `householderQr` only on diagonal system with singular values on diagonal (including zeros), and `householderQr` works ok, so at least it able to deal with singular matrices.

According to [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) `householderQr` should work with *any* matrix. So my question is - is it intended behaviour, or my mistake or bug in documentation/implementation?

My Eigen version is `3.4.0`, my compiler is GCC `11.2.0`